# Slide carousel is not working after page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When the below script runs, it prevents carousel from sliding.

Your help will be very much appreciated

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $("#reloadMwauwasa").load("data.php")
            }, 10000);
        });
    </script>
```

Note that I am not very familiar with jquery/javascript stuff.

Comment: Can you describe something details about your Question, and about `data.php`

Comment: The script you've provided does not concern itself with a carousel. It does however update the contents of an element with the `id="reloadMwauwasa"` attribute to be updated every 10 seconds with the contents from `data.php`. Is your carousel inside that element?

Comment: Please could you show us your URL and anything that concerns the carousel - there's no way of working out what has happened from the script you provided. Thanks.

Comment: Looks likely that your carousel is inside `#reloadMwauwasa` which you're overwriting each time.  The carousel would need to be reinitialised after loading, but it will be unusable if reset every 10 seconds.  We need more info on the carousel itself and what's in that div.   Have a read of [mcve] and provide us will all the information we need to recreate the issue.

Comment: here is the url https://app.strong11.co.tz/

Comment: The contents of that page is supposed to slide

Comment: if there is a way I can sent the entire file please